# Julia: Building symbol expressions

Tags: metaprogramming, julia

I have a repetitive set of boilerplate code that looks like this:

```
type Object
    ptr::Ptr{Void}

    function Object()
        ptr = ccall( (:createObject, LIB_SMILE), Ptr{Void}, ())
        smart_p = new(ptr)
        finalizer(smart_p, obj -> ccall( (:freeObject, LIB_SMILE), Void, (Ptr{Void},), obj.ptr ))
        smart_p
    end
end
```

I would like to auto-generate a set of these type definitions:

```
for str = ("Obj1","Obj2","Obj3")
    op_fname = symbol(str)
    op_create = ???
    op_free   = ???

    @eval begin
        type $op_fname
            ptr::Ptr{Void}

            function ($fname)()
                ptr = ccall( ($op_create, LIB_SMILE), Ptr{Void}, ())
                smart_p = new(ptr)
                finalizer(smart_p, obj -> ccall( ($op_free, LIB_SMILE), Void, (Ptr{Void},), obj.ptr ))
                smart_p
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I have not figured out how to generate the correct "symbol symbols" for op_create and op_free. As in, I need `op_create = :(:createObj)` but I cannot replicate this. Is there a way to generate the needed symbol in this context?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: the original answer works (see below), but as @mlubin points out, `QuoteNode` is an internal implementation function. The `quot` function in `Base.Meta` is better:

```
import Base.Meta.quot
str = "Obj1"
quot(symbol("create$str"))
```

returns `:(:createObj1)`. But I don't think that Meta.quot is documented either.

*Original answer:
You're looking for `QuoteNode`:*

```
str = "Obj1"
QuoteNode(symbol("create$str"))
```

*returns `:(:createObj1)` But this seems like a clear application for a macro!*

Comment: I came across it playing with expressions: `typeof(:(a + b + :c).args[4])` gives `QuoteNode`. That's about as much information as I have on it.

Comment: Better to use ``Meta.quot`` for this instead of ``QuoteNode``, which is a Julia internal.